# How to get count distinct in my chart without executing another query?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using jaspersoft studio 6.2. I have put a bar chart in summary band, how can I set it to count distinct of some field in the value expression?
e.g.

I have this query/dataset:

```
select 'xx' as UsageDate, 'a' as ProductName, 1 as CustomerKey
    union all select 'xx' as UsageDate, 'b' as ProductName, 1 as CustomerKey
    union all select 'xx' as UsageDate, 'a' as ProductName, 2 as CustomerKey
    union all select 'yy'as UsageDate, 'a' as ProductName, 1 as CustomerKey
    union all select 'yy' as UsageDate, 'b' as ProductName, 3 as CustomerKey
```

What I want to achieve is

```
select usagedate, productname, count(distinct customerkey) as val from (
    select 'xx' as UsageDate, 'a' as ProductName, 1 as CustomerKey
    union all select 'xx' as UsageDate, 'b' as ProductName, 1 as CustomerKey
    union all select 'xx' as UsageDate, 'a' as ProductName, 2 as CustomerKey
    union all select 'yy'as UsageDate, 'a' as ProductName, 1 as CustomerKey
    union all select 'yy' as UsageDate, 'b' as ProductName, 3 as CustomerKey    
    ) as t
    group by usagedate, productname
```

`usagedate` being category, `productname` being series. How can I set the value in the chart to be `count(distinct customerkey)`? I know I can use second query as dataset, and set the val field as the value in the chart, but I will also need to display details in the report so prefer just **one** query/dataset to do it all.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a datasource for your chart, so undoubtedly executing another query in subdatset is the easiest approach. However if you do not like to re-query another solution is to use a **report scriptlet**.

Create a class that extends the [JRDefaultScriptlet](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDefaultScriptlet.html) override the `afterDetailEval` get the value from your field, store the value and the count of it.

Then let your scriplet return the [JRDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html) for the chart.

**EDIT**: As simple example as asked for in comment

**The scriplet**

```
public class CountScriptlet extends JRDefaultScriptlet {

    private static final String COUNT_FIELD = "fieldNameYouLikeToCount";

    //Map to hold our count and dataset
    private Map<String,CountResult> ds = new HashMap<String, CountResult>(); 

    @Override
    public void afterDetailEval() throws JRScriptletException
    {
        String key = (String)this.getFieldValue(COUNT_FIELD);
        CountResult cr = ds.get(key); //Check if we have it
        if (cr==null){
            cr = new CountResult(key); //No, then create it count = 0
            ds.put(key, cr);
        }
        cr.increment(); //Increment it (new 0-->1, old i-->i+1

    }   
    public JRBeanCollectionDataSource getDataSource(){
        return new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(ds.values()); //Return our class as datasource, if you need to sort'em use Collections
    }
}
```

The class that **holds the count**

```
public class CountResult {

    private String description;
    private int count;

    public CountResult(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void increment(){
        count++;
    }
}
```

Tell **jrxml to use scriplet** (you need to indicate full class name including package name)

In `jasperReport` tag set `scriptletClass="CountScriptlet"`

Define the **subdataset**

```
<subDataset name="countDatasource" uuid="f6b4337c-45f4-4fc6-909a-ffbbef3a1b2f">
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="count" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
</subDataset>
```

**Use the datasource** where you like (piechart, table ecc.)

```
<datasetRun subDataset="countDatasource" uuid="92579588-802b-4073-a5ee-79672c9b6e66">
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
</datasetRun>
```

The only limitation is that the report need to have filled the detail band (finished the count), so you can use it in `summary` band or on `reportElement` with `evaluationTime="Report"`

Comment: Can you give more detail? I am no Java developer and new to Jasper studio. But would like to learn how to do it. I am from traditional BI world (SSRS, OBI), where this kind of operation is very easy and intuitive. I understand Jasper may be more for Java developers but would like to learn. Thanks.

Comment: @thotwielder, there you go, but you need some java to get the hang of it... : ), have fun