# Sum values for distinct keys (without grouping)

Tags: collections, sum, jasper-reports

## Background

Consider the following [data set](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/):

```
  Name   Mode   Tally
 ------ ------ -------
  N_1     M_1    1000
  N_2     M_3    4000
  N_3     M_2     500
  N_4     M_1    2000
  N_5     M_3    8000
```

The totals for **Mode** are:

```
  Mode   Total
 ------ -------
  M_1     3000
  M_2      500
  M_3    12000
```

The data is grouped by month and ordered by **Name**; it cannot be grouped by **Mode**. The entire set of values for **Mode** is unknown but finite (e.g., `M_1`, `M_2`, `M_3`, `M_x`, `M_y`, `M_z`, and so on).

## Problem

The **Mode** totals must be presented in the **Summary** band, which looks like a good candidate for a variable incremented using a [JRDistinctCountIncrementer](https://sourceforge.net/p/jasperreports/code/ci/6.3.0.x/tree/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/JRDistinctCountIncrementerFactory.java#l73) (using an incrementer factory class name of [JRDistinctCountIncrementerFactory](https://sourceforge.net/p/jasperreports/code/ci/6.3.0.x/tree/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/JRDistinctCountIncrementerFactory.java#l35)). Part of the problem is that the [documentation](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) is lacking.

## Example Output

To give a clear picture of the intended usage:

[image: Report Layout]

Note how the elements in the **Tx Subtotals** section re-use existing styles and align with existing columns. Writing String values to the **Summary** band using a Scriptlet would work, provided the Scriptlet can expose iterable data.

## Approach 1

The list of totals summed for each distinct tuple (e.g., mode and tally) must be retrieved after the report rows have been filled. That list is then passed into a subreport as a [JRMapCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRMapCollectionDataSource.html). That subreport is placed on the **Summary** band of the main report.

For this, a variable must be created, along the lines of:

- **Name:** `modes`
- **Value Class Name:** `java.util.Map` ?
- **Calculation:** `No Calculation Function` ?
- **Expression:** `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry( $F{mode}, $F{tally} )` ?
- **Initial Value Expression:** ?
- **Increment type:** `None`
- **Incrementer Factory Class Name:** ?
- **Reset type:** `Report`

This would allow the subreport's **Data Source Expression** to be:

```
new JRMapCollectionDataSource( $V{modes} )
```

## Approach 2

Create a `MappedIncrementerFactory` and `MappedIncrementer`, similar to `JRDistinctCountIncrementerFactory` and `JRDistinctCountIncrementer`.

## Approach 3

Pre-calculate the grand totals and pass them in using a data object model. For example:

```
public class DataSetItem {
    public String getName() { ... }
    public String getMode() { ... }
    public Integer getTally() { ... }
}

public class DataSet {
    public List<DataSetItem> getDataSetItemList() { ... }
    public Map<String, Integer> getDataSetTotals() { ... }
}

public class DataSetFactory {
    /** Returns a single instance that has the list of items and totals. */
    public List<DataSet> createDataSetItemCollection() { ... }
}
```

## Approach 4

Use a Scriptlet and return a `JRDataSource` for the values.

## Question

How would you create a variable of type collection (a map) that contains key/value pairs where each value is the sum of report rows that match the key name?

Comment: I'm not sure I would use a Map, but immagine on `afterDetailEval()` to collect your data (in Map or in Objects), then add a method that returns a `JRDataSource` that you use in summary band, something like this but adapted to your example http://stackoverflow.com/a/36691660/5292302

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution follows. The names for the key and value column tuples are set as parameters in the subreport. The master report contains the scriptlet, the subreport, and the grand totals summary page. This is useful in the situation where there are a number of virtually identical subreports, but only some of them require grand totals based on column tuples.

Each subreport with grand total tuples must define a value for the **key parameter**  and value for the **value parameter**: `SCRIPTLET_KEY_COLUMN_NAME` and `SCRIPTLET_VALUE_COLUMN_NAME`, respectively. If the key parameter isn't set in the subreport, then `isSubreport()` will return false and no summations will be performed.

## Scriptlet

The master report runs the following scriptlet, which is configured by setting the **Scriptlet Class** to `com.company.jasper.TupleSumScriptlet`.

```
package com.company.jasper;

import java.util.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;

public class TupleSumScriplet extends JRDefaultScriptlet {
    private final static String REPORT_KEY_COLUMN_NAME
            = "SCRIPTLET_KEY_COLUMN_NAME";
    private final static String REPORT_VALUE_COLUMN_NAME
            = "SCRIPTLET_VALUE_COLUMN_NAME";

    private final Map<String, Integer> sums = new HashMap<>();

    public TupleSumScriplet() { }

    @Override
    public void afterDetailEval() throws JRScriptletException {
        if (isSubreport()) {
            final String keyColumnName = getKeyColumnName();
            final String key = (String) getFieldValue(keyColumnName);

            final String valueColumnName = getValueColumnName();
            final int value = (Integer) getFieldValue(valueColumnName);

            final Map<String, Integer> totals = getSums();
            final int sum = totals.containsKey(key) ? totals.get(key) : 0;

            totals.put(key, sum + value);
        }
    }

    public JRDataSource getDataSource() {
        return new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(sort(getSums()));
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getSums() {
        return this.sums;
    }

    private String getKeyColumnName() throws JRScriptletException {
        return (String) getParameterValue(REPORT_KEY_COLUMN_NAME);
    }

    protected String getValueColumnName() throws JRScriptletException {
        return (String) getParameterValue(REPORT_VALUE_COLUMN_NAME);
    }

    private boolean isSubreport() {
        boolean result;

        try {
            result = true;
            final String unused = getKeyColumnName();

        } catch (JRScriptletException e) {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static
            <K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> Collection<Map.Entry<K, V>>
            sort(Map<K, V> map) {
        final List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list = new LinkedList<>(map.entrySet());

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2) {
                return (o1.getKey()).compareTo(o2.getKey());
            }
        });

        return list;
    }
}
```

## Master Report

The JRXML for the master report includes:

- **Detail band** subreport
- **Summary band** Grand Totals subreport

The **Detail band** subreport element must have a `REPORT_SCRIPLET` parameter passed in using `$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}` from the master report.

The **Summary band** subreport element (Grand Totals) is trivial because it uses the API defined by `Map.EntrySet<K, V>`, which exposes `getKey` and `getValue` methods. These methods directly mapped to fields, which are defined and used in the subreport--as `key` and `value`, respectively. The element must also have its **Data Source Expression** set to:

```
$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getDataSource()
```

The relevant JRXML for the Grand Totals subreport follows:

```xml
<field name="key" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[key]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="value" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[value]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<detail>
    <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="75" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{key}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement x="75" y="0" width="150" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

## Example Output

This produces the desired results and requires no modifications to Java source code in the event that the tuple's column names change.

[image: Example Filled Report]

Answer (score 3):

## This would be Approach 4: Using [JRScriplet](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRScriptlet.html)

### The scriplet class

The scriplet will sum and store data to later (after all detail's) return a datasource. Note: `Nullpointer` or other problems with the datasource are not considered.

```
public class Scriplet extends JRDefaultScriptlet {

    private Map<String, TxSubTotal> subTotals; //Use map for quick access
    private int lastRecNr = 0; //Jasper has a bad habit of calling twice

    public Scriplet(){
        super();
        subTotals = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterDetailEval() throws JRScriptletException {
        int recNr = ((Integer)this.getVariableValue("REPORT_COUNT")); 
        if (lastRecNr==recNr){ //Check we only count once per record
            return;
        }
        lastRecNr=recNr;
        String key = (String)this.getFieldValue("Mode");
        int value = ((Integer)this.getFieldValue("Tally")).intValue();

        TxSubTotal tst = subTotals.get(key);
        if (tst == null){
            tst = new TxSubTotal(key);
            subTotals.put(key, tst);
        }
        tst.addTotal(value);
        super.afterDetailEval();
    }

    //This is our datasource
    public JRRewindableDataSource getSubTotalDataSource(){
        List<TxSubTotal> txList = new ArrayList<>();
        //add some sorting to show the power of scriplet
        txList.addAll(subTotals.values());
        Collections.sort(txList);
        return new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(txList);
    }
}
```

### The Bean that holds the data

This been holds the data and implements `Comparable` for some nice sorting

```
public class TxSubTotal implements Comparable<TxSubTotal>{
    private String mode;
    private int total;
    public TxSubTotal(String key) {
        mode = key;
    }
    public String getMode() {
        return mode;
    }
    public void setMode(String mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }
    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
    public void addTotal(int value){
        this.total+=value;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(TxSubTotal o) {
        return mode.compareTo(o.getMode());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof TxSubTotal){
            return mode.equals(((TxSubTotal)obj).getMode());    
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return mode.hashCode();
    }
}
```

### The jrxml

Set scriptlet to report

```
scriptletClass="Scriplet"
```

This jrxml use the `jr:table` component to display the data but a subreport can be used as well. The key is to use it in summary band or to have `evaluationTime="report"` on the table/subreport component. The datasource expression will be

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getSubTotalDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

Full jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Jarvis" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" scriptletClass="Scriplet" uuid="d626fd77-14da-4974-8b4f-6368e913ac91">
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="subTotals" uuid="486941af-2c8f-4ebb-8b8a-7a1dfe2ac0ad">
        <field name="mode" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="total" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Mode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Tally" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="30cd16d8-6765-42f9-b5f9-22bc0625adca"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="88418f9a-5d2b-487e-b04d-e11bc57726d7"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Mode]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="dd2495bb-3a3d-4b0e-b986-055bf55cf19b"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Tally]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="53931171-df80-43e7-9b9d-5d77ce4223dc"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="f809c675-c68b-4ad0-b662-23ba6e9dd70c"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Mode}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="0852ff01-aa61-4a7f-9c11-a481b78b56fd"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Tally}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="75" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table" style="table" x="120" y="25" width="180" height="50" uuid="5158e7c3-d87d-4877-a3ab-d6a6f9a57c5a"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="subTotals" uuid="9b73e50e-4bdf-41c2-8d40-4d215fe6b6e9">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getSubTotalDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="cbb85338-16b3-487d-8045-6dd94c661fc0">
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="5c07b5af-9e28-4a14-a70a-3789bfc88087"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mode}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="d69567f0-ec7c-4b83-bc22-5aae1cab7879">
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="2a3a2055-f9c0-46e3-b816-b6ee1c989f9c"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{total}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="120" y="5" width="180" height="20" uuid="9ef22e85-34ce-47c9-afad-2813a8a0b863"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Tx SubTotals]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

### Main method to generate pdf export from a cvs file containing data in question

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException, FileNotFoundException {
    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("myReport.jrxml");

    JRCsvDataSource datasource = new JRCsvDataSource(new File("data/datasource.csv"));
    datasource.setFieldDelimiter(';');
    datasource.setUseFirstRowAsHeader(true);
    datasource.setLocale(Locale.US);

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String, Object>(), datasource);

    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();       
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("pdf/example.pdf"));
    SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
    exporter.exportReport();
}
```

### The result

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you. No idea how you managed to pull that off so quickly. That said, I've taken a slightly different approach that obviates the need for an additional bean by using the getKey and getValue methods from `Map.EntrySet`. See my answer for details.

Comment: @DaveJarvis, *quickly*, as SE staff I copy and past in true SO FGITW spirit, yes nice answer, however my personal preference is to always map to object, you never know if next FR request of client is to also have distinct count, mean value of entries etc.